# How futures contracts are managed by the exchange

Tags: futures, derivatives, options-exchanges

Please, confirm my current understanding of how futures work. Let’s consider cash-settled futures for simplicity.

1. The number of futures contracts (with identical parameters) is unlimited. New futures contract will be created by the exchange as long as there is a matching buyer and seller.
2. Any person can sell a futures contract - one does’t have to own it first.
3. If you own a contract you can sell it on the exchange. For other exchange players it will be completely opaque whether it is a newly created futures contract (created by the exchange) or an existing one, sold by its owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes all three are true, but just to clear up some terminology (which may make it easier to understand):

You do not "buy" and "sell" futures contracts. You *enter into* a contract to either buy or sell some underlying commodity or financial instrument at a fixed price on a fixed date. So you do not need to "own" a futures contract toi "sell" it - what you're really doing is entering into a contract to sell something (which you also don't have to own at that time).

And yes, the "buying and selling" of futures is completely handled by the exchange - counterparties have no idea who is holding the other end of their contract, and all settlements are done through the exchange.

Answer (score 1):

**#1 is not true.** There are Position Limits applied by CFTC and the Exchange to each trader or each group of affiliated traders.

For example, NYMEX CL (Light Sweet Crude Oil Futures) has a Position Limit of 10000 contracts for each expiring month, applied by CME.

https://www.cftc.gov/IndustryOversight/MarketSurveillance/SpeculativeLimits/index.htm

https://www.cmegroup.com/market-regulation/position-limits.html

Comment: Can you please confirm that #2 and #3 are true?

Comment: It's true to me, unless someone else thinks of some "edge case".

Comment: Well, there are position limits per trader/institution, but the theoretical number of contracts in the market overall is limitless. If you want to trade a future, and aren't at a position limit of your own, you can probably do so.